# C++ : Pointers to Strings

Tags: c++, string

```
char name[]="samina",*p=name;
while (*p)
    cout<<*p++;
cout<<endl<<p-name;
```

I have a string `name` and a pointer `p`. Now the while loop updates the pointer to each character of the string and displays the string.

But the expression `p-name` always display the length of the string. According to me, at the end of the loop `p` points to `'\0'` and name points to 's' so shouldn't the output give the ascii code of letter 's'?

Comment: Why would it give the ascii code of `s`?

Comment: For ascii code, use `name[0] - p[0]`

Comment: Guys, can you help make me understand the concept please?

Comment: @MohitJain Then what does p-name do?

Comment: p is pointing to last char. `p - name` is number of characters + 1 between name and p.

Comment: _"Then what does p-name do?"_ Simple pointer arithmetics calculating the offset for these pointers.

Comment: @MohitJain Okay Thanks a lot!

Comment: The concept of pointer you can read more about on blogs this is not magic its just pointing concept for memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer P can't be Initialized by none-address values (you should Initialize a pointer with an address).

char* p = &name[0]

Comment: No no, you didnt understand my question. I want to know what p-name  does. And btw char *p=name works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `name` is stored at the address of `0x20304050`, while `p` points to the `address` of `0x20304060` after increasing it `0x10` times.

`p address` - `name address` = `0x10`, that's why you get that result.

Perhaps this is what yo want instead:

```
 cout << (*p) /*0*/ - (*name) /*115*/; // = -115
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard (5.7 Additive operators)

> 6 When two pointers to elements of the same array object are
>   subtracted, the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements. The type of the result is an implementation-defined
>   signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined
>   as std::ptrdiff_t in the  header (18.2). As with any other
>   arithmetic overflow, if the result does not fit in the space provided,
>   the behavior is undefined. **In other words, if the expressions P and
>   Q point to, respectively, the i-th and j-th elements of an array
>   object, the expression (P)-(Q) has the value i − j** provided the
>   value fits in an object of type std::ptrdiff_t. Moreover, if the
>   expression P points either to an element of an array object or one
>   past the last element of an array object, and the expression Q points
>   to the last element of the same array object, the expression
>   ((Q)+1)-(P) has the same value as ((Q)-(P))+1 and as -((P)-((Q)+1)),
>   and has the value zero if the expression P points one past the last
>   element of the array object, even though the expression (Q)+1 does not
>   point to an element of the array object. Unless both pointers point to
>   elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the
>   array object, the behavior is undefined.

So in your code snippet after the loop expression `p - name` contains the number of elements in the array between the first character and the zero character.

If you would use expression `*name - *p` where each operand is of type `char` in this case you had `'s' - '\0'` that is equal to the integer vakue corresponding to the code of the character `'s'`

Answer (score 0):

Initially, p is pointing to the whole string (actually to the beginning of the string) as you have declared it, to the same value as name does. When you subtract one from the other, it subtracts their addresses. At the end, as p is pointing to the end of the string, but name is still pointing to the beginning of it, so p-name = 6.